# my java tf-idf program isn't reading the file it's supposed to

Tags: java, filereader, tf-idf

The program is supposed to read a file, where the filename will be arquivo.txt, and should read its content and calculate the tf-idf of a term that the user will insert, but it says that couldn't locate the arquivo.txt file, even thought its on the src file of the program.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile {
    public static String readFile(String filename) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(input.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conteudo = readFile("arquivo.txt") ;
        System.out.println(conteudo);

        double idf = Math.log(1/1);
        System.out.println("informe o termo");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String term = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("informe o documento(arquivo/nome do arquivo)");
        String doc = in.nextLine();

    }



    public class TFIDFCalculator {
        public double tf(List <String> doc, String term) {
            double result = 0;
            for (String word : doc) {
                if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                    result++;
            }
            return result / doc.size();
        }

        public double idf(List <List <String>> docs, String term) {
            double n = 0;
            for (List <String> doc : docs) {
                for (String word : doc) {
                    if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                        n++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Math.log(docs.size() / n);
        }

        public double tfidf(List <String> doc, List <List <String>> docs, String term) {
            return tf(doc, term) * idf(docs, term);
        }

    

    }
}
```

tried programing the code on a different style, the result it wont show the run option, like the IntelliJ won't find the runnable part.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        List wordList = new ArrayList();
        String conteudo = readFile("arquivo.txt") ;
        String[] parts = conteudo.split("_");
        int i =0;
        for (String part: parts) {
            wordList.add(parts[i]);i++;
        }
        System.out.println(conteudo);

        double idf = Math.log(1/1);
        System.out.println("informe o termo");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String term = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("informe o documento(arquivo/nome do arquivo)");
        String doc = in.nextLine();
        double actualTfidf = tfidf(wordList,wordList, "work");
        System.out.println("the tfidf is "+ actualTfidf);

    }
    //methods
    private double tfidf(List <String> doc, List <List <String>> docs, String term) {
        return tf(doc, term) * idf(docs, term);
    }

    public static String readFile(String filename) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(input.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public double idf(List <List <String>> docs, String term) {
        double n = 0;
        for (List <String> doc : docs) {
            for (String word : doc) {
                if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                    n++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return Math.log(docs.size() / n);
    }

    public double tf(List <String> doc, String term) {
        double result = 0;
        for (String word : doc) {
            if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                result++;
        }
        return result / doc.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check how you are running the program, specifically what is the current working directory when running it.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the file by its absolute path? Does that work? Please consider working with java.nio.file (the native file system library) instead of java.io.file.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this. But if your file is in the `src` folder (where the `.java` files are located), then keep in mind that IDEs (like Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ) will usually compile the `.java` files and create the `.class` files for them. These `.class` files are often put into a `bin` or `classes` folder. And **these** are the actual "program" that is started then. So you *could* place the `.txt` into that folder, or (better and cleaner) consider other options, like proper file paths or treating the file as a *resource*

Comment: @Marco13 i looked up what you said, and within the place where the .classe files are, there`s already a exact copy of the .txt file wich i want to read, the IDE i`m using is Intellij.

Comment: Then, as a first test, I'd try an absolute path (like `C:/Workspace/myFile.txt`), but **only** as a first test. Then you could place the file into the root directory of your project, and try `readFile("./arquivo.txt");` (note the `./`).

Comment: The `src` folder is on the classpath. It is not accessible as a `File` as it ends up in a `.jar`. You can get it to work from an IDE because they run exploded, but the classpath root is not the CWD. So if you want to have the file on the classpath, then you are going to have to use the classloader to access it. If you want to have the file on the filesystem, then don't place it in `src`.